# How can I hide my exception stack trace in python code which is deployed on aws lambda and integrated with API gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, exception, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I use raise Exception (" message ") and it returns this on browser
{"errorMessage": "{"httpStatus": 200, "message": "Exception: {\"httpStatus\": 200, \"message\": \"Exception: [InternalServerError] Project not found\"}"}", "errorType": "Exception", "stackTrace": [the stack trace]}

The stack trace causes security issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using API gateway in front of lambda. You can set reponse mapping template like below, this will override the response error message and response code as well.

```
#if($inputRoot.toString().contains('InternalServerError'))
{
  "message": "Internal Server Error"
}
#set($context.responseOverride.status = 500)
```

Alternately you can also catch all the exceptions in the lambda and return whatever you like. However this will not override the status code and you would still get 200 even in case of error.

```
def handler(event, context):
   try:
       dosomething(event)
   except Exception:
       retunrn { "message": "Internal Server error" }

def dosomething(event):
      .... You business logic.
```